# Is there way to get all of a contract's events as an array instead of each one separately?

Tags: web3js, events

I'm using Web3's `allEvents()` method to get all the events on a specific contract, and it's working great, except each event pops into the callback separately.

That turns into a bit of a pain when I want to create an array of all the events, as it's hard to discern when the callback has been fired 'enough' times.

Is there a method - in Web3 or otherwise - to get all the events as one array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out almost immediately. Instead of using

`myContract.allEvents(filterObject, (e, res) => console.log(res))`

I should have been using

`myContract.allEvents(filterObject).get((e, res) => console.log(res))`

Comment: Do you have an answer for Web3 1.0? It seems that this is still a problem, but I don't have a solution. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73137/how-do-you-parse-web3-retuned-json-objects-of-events